# .NET Core - C# - MacOS | Keychain API

Tags: c#, .net-core, keychain

Trying to set/get some passwords into Keychain on MacOS, using C#. Managed to add Xamarin.iOS assembly, but can't seem to go further. This is what I have,

```
using System;
using Security;
using Foundation;

var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.InternetPassword)
{
    Server = "bugzilla.novell.com",
    Account = "miguel"
};
```

But get an exception, which isn't that useful. I am not sure what value is null. This above example is straight from [Xamarin website](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Security.SecRecord/), but doesn't work. New to this Keychain business, so not sure what I am missing.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help, please? Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have also tried to instantiate without the enum, but still get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Look at `SecKind.InternetPassword` [in your debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/).

Comment: @DourHighArch `SecKind.InternetPassword` is an enum - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Security.SecKind/

Comment: Anyone?  Bump :)

Comment: Sorry, dont have a macOS :)

Comment: Just found one [crappy] way - https://ss64.com/osx/security.html. Though crappy, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to solve this by calling `security` cmd - https://ss64.com/osx/security.html

But if anyone knows how this can be done via API and using C#, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You must properly initialize the Objective-C runtime as documented in [Using Xamarin.Mac bindings for Console Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/console) before using Apple native APIs in C#:

```cs
NSApplication.Init();
```

Actually, calling `ObjCRuntime.Runtime.EnsureInitialized();` would be enough but unlike `NSApplication.Init()`, the `EnsureInitialized()` method is internal and thus only callable through reflection, which is probably not a good idea.